# DevExpress GridControl cell enabling/disabling

Tags: grid, devexpress, cell

I have a grid control where some columns are editable, some are not.

I'd like to have more fine control, so that **depending on some other fields of `MyData`, the corresponding cells will be enabled or not**.

```
    <dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}" AutoPopulateColumns="True">
            <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                <dxg:GridColumn Header="Name" ReadOnly="True"/>
                <dxg:GridColumn Header="ID 1" ReadOnly="False"/>
                <dxg:GridColumn Header="ID 2" ReadOnly="False"/>
                <dxg:GridColumn Header="ID 3" ReadOnly="False"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
   </dxg:GridControl>
```

Can't find anything on the DevExpress support site yet. Would you please have any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this task via handling the [ShowingEditor](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridGridViewBase_ShowingEditortopic) event. You can set `e.Cancel` to `True` if a cell shouldn't be edited:

```
void TableView_ShowingEditor(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.ShowingEditorEventArgs e)
{
    if(...)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

You can also accomplish this task via XAML style:

```
<Style TargetType="dxg:CellContentPresenter" BasedOn="{StaticResource {dxgt:GridRowThemeKey ResourceKey=CellStyle}}">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=RowData.Row.SomePropertyRelatedToEnabledState}"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you will try. This is code behind though, would there be some way to do this in xaml by binding the cell's ReadOnly property to another one on the VM?

Comment: @goul: I've updated my answer with style-based approach.

Comment: Thank you!
I've been able to make it with the code behind, however it seems that with the xaml (I'd prefer), it is setting the style to all the cells, so not only the row where the property bound has been changed. I've tried using triggers but no luck.
Reason I want to use the XAML and triggers is that I'd also like to set the style of the cell to bold when enabled.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @goul you can extend my xaml-approach to "per-cell customization"  with easy via adding some special value-converter that will take into account the Column property...

Comment: I've tired but can't find how the converter could take ino account the column. Here is my code: `<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=RowData.Row.IdSet1, Converter={conv:valueColumnConvertr}}"/>`. Thanks

Comment: @goul To accomplish passing multiple values into binding you should take a look at [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding(v=vs.110).aspx) approach and  related [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx).